# cartographer + move_base，Control loop missed its desired rate

Tags: ros, navigation, cartographer, ros-kinetic, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Cartographer + move_base runs at the same time,Control loop missed its desired rate。(cmd_val frequency is extremely low)**

The computer used is: **NVIDIA Jetson TX2**, cpu utilization is close to 100%. Is this a normal phenomenon or a configuration problem?

```
 **SUMMARY**
========

PARAMETERS

 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/acc_lim_theta: 0.5
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/acc_lim_x: 0.5
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/allow_init_with_backwards_motion: False
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/costmap_converter/CostmapToLinesDBSRANSAC/cluster_max_distance: 0.4
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/costmap_converter/CostmapToLinesDBSRANSAC/cluster_min_pts: 2
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/costmap_converter/CostmapToLinesDBSRANSAC/convex_hull_min_pt_separation: 0.1
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/costmap_converter/CostmapToLinesDBSRANSAC/ransac_convert_outlier_pts: True
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/costmap_converter/CostmapToLinesDBSRANSAC/ransac_filter_remaining_outlier_pts: False
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/costmap_converter/CostmapToLinesDBSRANSAC/ransac_inlier_distance: 0.15
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/costmap_converter/CostmapToLinesDBSRANSAC/ransac_min_inliers: 10
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/costmap_converter/CostmapToLinesDBSRANSAC/ransac_no_iterations: 1500
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/costmap_converter/CostmapToLinesDBSRANSAC/ransac_remainig_outliers: 3
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/costmap_converter_plugin: costmap_converter...
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/costmap_converter_rate: 5
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/costmap_converter_spin_thread: True
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/costmap_obstacles_behind_robot_dist: 1.5
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/dt_hysteresis: 0.1
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/dt_ref: 0.3
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/enable_homotopy_class_planning: True
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/enable_multithreading: True
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/feasibility_check_no_poses: 5
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/footprint_model/type: point
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/free_goal_vel: False
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/global_plan_overwrite_orientation: True
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/h_signature_prescaler: 0.5
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/h_signature_threshold: 0.1
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/include_costmap_obstacles: True
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/map_frame: /map
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/max_global_plan_lookahead_dist: 3.0
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/max_number_classes: 4
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/max_vel_theta: 1.0
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/max_vel_x: 1.0
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/max_vel_x_backwards: 0.6
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/max_vel_y: 0.0
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/min_obstacle_dist: 0.5
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/min_turning_radius: 0.0
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/no_inner_iterations: 5
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/no_outer_iterations: 4
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/obstacle_heading_threshold: 0.45
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/obstacle_keypoint_offset: 0.1
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/obstacle_poses_affected: 30
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/odom_topic: odom
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/optimization_activate: True
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/optimization_verbose: False
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/oscillation_filter_duration: 10
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/oscillation_omega_eps: 0.1
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/oscillation_recovery: True
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/oscillation_recovery_min_duration: 10
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/oscillation_v_eps: 0.1
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/penalty_epsilon: 0.1
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/roadmap_graph_area_width: 5
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/roadmap_graph_no_samples: 15
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/selection_alternative_time_cost: False
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/selection_cost_hysteresis: 1.0
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/selection_obst_cost_scale: 1.0
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/shrink_horizon_backup: True
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/shrink_horizon_min_duration: 10
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/simple_exploration: False
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/teb_autosize: True
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/visualize_hc_graph: False
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/weight_acc_lim_theta: 1
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/weight_acc_lim_x: 1
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/weight_adapt_factor: 2
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/weight_dynamic_obstacle: 10
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/weight_kinematics_forward_drive: 1
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/weight_kinematics_nh: 1000
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/weight_kinematics_turning_radius: 1
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/weight_max_vel_theta: 1
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/weight_max_vel_x: 2
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/weight_obstacle: 50
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/weight_optimaltime: 1
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/xy_goal_tolerance: 0.2
 * /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.1
 * /move_base/base_local_planner: teb_local_planner...
 * /move_base/controller_frequency: 10.0
 * /move_base/global_costmap/cost_scaling_factor: 10.0
 * /move_base/global_costmap/footprint: [[0.51, 0.35], [0...
 * /move_base/global_costmap/footprint_padding: 0.02
 * /move_base/global_costmap/global_frame: map
 * /move_base/global_costmap/inflation_layer/cost_scaling_factor: 10.0
 * /move_base/global_costmap/inflation_layer/enabled: True
 * /move_base/global_costmap/inflation_layer/inflation_radius: 0.5
 * /move_base/global_costmap/map_type: costmap
 * /move_base/global_costmap/obstacle_layer/combination_method: 1
 * /move_base/global_costmap/obstacle_layer/enabled: True
 * /move_base/global_costmap/obstacle_layer/observation_sources: point_cloud_sensor
 * /move_base/global_costmap/obstacle_layer/obstacle_range: 5.0
 * /move_base/global_costmap/obstacle_layer/point_cloud_sensor/clearing: True
 * /move_base/global_costmap/obstacle_layer/point_cloud_sensor/data_type: PointCloud2
 * /move_base/global_costmap/obstacle_layer/point_cloud_sensor/marking: True
 * /move_base/global_costmap/obstacle_layer/point_cloud_sensor/max_obstacle_height: 0.8
 * /move_base/global_costmap/obstacle_layer/point_cloud_sensor/min_obstacle_height: 0.07
 * /move_base/global_costmap/obstacle_layer/point_cloud_sensor/sensor_frame: laser_link
 * /move_base/global_costmap/obstacle_layer/point_cloud_sensor/topic: /lslidar_point_cloud
 * /move_base/global_costmap/obstacle_layer/raytrace_range: 5.5
 * /move_base/global_costmap/obstacle_layer/track_unknown_space: True
 * /move_base/global_costmap/plugins: [{'type': 'costma...
 * /move_base/global_costmap/publish_frequency: 1.0
 * /move_base/global_costmap/resolution: 0.05
 * /move_base/global_costmap/robot_base_frame: base_link
 * /move_base/global_costmap/rolling_windows: False
 * /move_base/global_costmap/static_layer/enabled: True
 * /move_base/global_costmap/static_layer/map_topic: /map
 * /move_base/global_costmap/static_map: True
 * /move_base/global_costmap/transform_tolerance: 2.0
 * /move_base/global_costmap/update_frequency: 1.0
 * /move_base/local_costmap/cost_scaling_factor: 10.0
 * /move_base/local_costmap/footprint: [[0.51, 0.35], [0...
 * /move_base/local_costmap/global_frame: odom
 * /move_base/local_costmap/height: 8.0
 * /move_base/local_costmap/inflation_layer/cost_scaling_factor: 10.0
 * /move_base/local_costmap/inflation_layer/enabled: True
 * /move_base/local_costmap/inflation_layer/inflation_radius: 0.5
 * /move_base/local_costmap/map_type: costmap
 * /move_base/local_costmap/obstacle_layer/combination_method: 1
 * /move_base/local_costmap/obstacle_layer/enabled: True
 * /move_base/local_costmap/obstacle_layer/observation_sources: point_cloud_sensor
 * /move_base/local_costmap/obstacle_layer/obstacle_range: 5.0
 * /move_base/local_costmap/obstacle_layer/point_cloud_sensor/clearing: True
 * /move_base/local_costmap/obstacle_layer/point_cloud_sensor/data_type: PointCloud2
 * /move_base/local_costmap/obstacle_layer/point_cloud_sensor/marking: True
 * /move_base/local_costmap/obstacle_layer/point_cloud_sensor/max_obstacle_height: 0.8
 * /move_base/local_costmap/obstacle_layer/point_cloud_sensor/min_obstacle_height: 0.07
 * /move_base/local_costmap/obstacle_layer/point_cloud_sensor/sensor_frame: laser_link
 * /move_base/local_costmap/obstacle_layer/point_cloud_sensor/topic: /lslidar_point_cloud
 * /move_base/local_costmap/obstacle_layer/raytrace_range: 5.5
 * /move_base/local_costmap/obstacle_layer/track_unknown_space: True
 * /move_base/local_costmap/origin_x: 0.0
 * /move_base/local_costmap/origin_y: 0.0
 * /move_base/local_costmap/plugins: [{'type': 'costma...
 * /move_base/local_costmap/publish_frequency: 2.0
 * /move_base/local_costmap/resolution: 0.05
 * /move_base/local_costmap/robot_base_frame: base_link
 * /move_base/local_costmap/rolling_window: True
 * /move_base/local_costmap/static_layer/enabled: True
 * /move_base/local_costmap/static_layer/map_topic: /map
 * /move_base/local_costmap/static_map: False
 * /move_base/local_costmap/transform_tolerance: 0.5
 * /move_base/local_costmap/update_frequency: 1.0
 * /move_base/local_costmap/width: 8.0
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.14
 * /use_sim_time: False

NODES
  /
    move_base (move_base/move_base)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://sucro:11311
process[move_base-1]: started with pid [24033]
[ INFO] [1563279112.680718184]: Using plugin "static_layer"
[ INFO] [1563279112.706138141]: Requesting the map...
[ INFO] [1563279113.821924826]: Resizing costmap to 646 X 680 at 0.050000 m/pix
[ INFO] [1563279113.920038303]: Received a 646 X 680 map at 0.050000 m/pix
[ INFO] [1563279113.956386472]: Using plugin "obstacle_layer"
[ INFO] [1563279113.984475923]:     Subscribed to Topics: point_cloud_sensor
[ INFO] [1563279114.095349931]: Using plugin "inflation_layer"

[ INFO] [1563279114.309531726]: Using plugin "static_layer"
[ INFO] [1563279114.331807012]: Requesting the map...
[ INFO] [1563279114.383891308]: Resizing static layer to 646 X 680 at 0.050000 m/pix
[ INFO] [1563279114.442643690]: Received a 646 X 680 map at 0.050000 m/pix
[ INFO] [1563279114.470681243]: Using plugin "obstacle_layer"
[ INFO] [1563279114.488237586]:     Subscribed to Topics: point_cloud_sensor
[ INFO] [1563279114.605745167]: Using plugin "inflation_layer"
[ INFO] [1563279114.802155379]: Created local_planner teb_local_planner/TebLocalPlannerROS
[ INFO] [1563279115.243505147]: Footprint model 'point' loaded for trajectory optimization.
[ INFO] [1563279115.243676078]: Parallel planning in distinctive topologies enabled.
[ INFO] [1563279115.412600909]: Costmap conversion plugin costmap_converter::CostmapToLinesDBSRANSAC loaded.
[ INFO] [1563279116.779101393]: Recovery behavior will clear layer obstacles
[ INFO] [1563279116.804937808]: Recovery behavior will clear layer obstacles

[ WARN] [1563279137.449122714]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 10.0000Hz... the loop actually took 7.5072 seconds

[ INFO] [1563279138.784172362]: Resizing costmap to 650 X 680 at 0.050000 m/pix
[ INFO] [1563279138.795393838]: Resizing static layer to 650 X 680 at 0.050000 m/pix


 [ WARN] [1563279156.227073295]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 10.0000Hz... the loop actually took
18.7780 seconds
    [ WARN] [1563279156.227821820]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 1.0000Hz... the loop actually took 25.4829 seconds

[ INFO] [1563279157.793498312]: Resizing costmap to 652 X 680 at 0.050000 m/pix
[ INFO] [1563279157.806379798]: Resizing static layer to 652 X 680 at 0.050000 m/pix
[ WARN] [1563279165.678858883]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 10.0000Hz... the loop actually took 9.4518 seconds
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328653/cartographer-+-move_base%EF%BC%8Ccontrol-loop-missed-its-desired-rate/) by [Tansor](https://answers.ros.org/users/39183/tansor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2019-07-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
/move_base/local_costmap/obstacle_layer/obstacle_range: 5.0
/move_base/local_costmap/obstacle_layer/raytrace_range: 5.5
```

Appropriately reduce these two parameters

---

Originally posted by [Tansor](https://answers.ros.org/users/39183/tansor/) with karma: 40 on 2019-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're trying to do too much with your CPU, if you're at 100% utilization, you're missing rate because you don't have enough cycles to accomplish that processes computational tasks.

You'll need to either do less, offload some computation, or try to tune things to run at tractable rates. The rule of thumb for this type of thing is to have your CPU running at about 80% so that there's enough juice for the sudden bursts of work.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2019-07-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tansor](https://answers.ros.org/users/39183/tansor/) on 2019-07-17**:
Thank you very much for your answer！
I have enhanced cpu performance, and now the occupancy rate is around 60%, but there are still the above problems.

```
[ INFO] [1563279138.784172362]: Resizing costmap to 650 X 680 at 0.050000 m/pix
[ INFO] [1563279138.795393838]: Resizing static layer to 650 X 680 at 0.050000 m/pix
[ WARN] [1563279156.227073295]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 10.0000Hz... the loop actually took18.7780 seconds
[ WARN] [1563279156.227821820]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 1.0000Hz... the loop actually took 25.4829 seconds.
```

The terminal always prompts Resizing costmap, is this normal?